# rspec and plugin generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have rails project with rspec as default test framework. On attempt to generate new plugin i see following:

```
test1 alec$ rails g plugin o2p -g -t
      create  vendor/plugins/o2p
      create  vendor/plugins/o2p/MIT-LICENSE
      create  vendor/plugins/o2p/README
      create  vendor/plugins/o2p/Rakefile
      create  vendor/plugins/o2p/init.rb
      create  vendor/plugins/o2p/install.rb
      create  vendor/plugins/o2p/uninstall.rb
      create  vendor/plugins/o2p/lib
      create  vendor/plugins/o2p/lib/o2p.rb
      invoke  generator
      inside    vendor/plugins/o2p
      create      lib/generators
      create      lib/generators/o2p_generator.rb
      create      lib/generators/USAGE
      create      lib/generators/templates
       error  rspec [not found]
```

I've confused with line "error  rspec [not found]". What's the problem with using rspec generators in rails plugin?

Comment: How have you specified RSpec in your application? I'm interested in how you set it to be the default and also it's positioning in the Gemfile. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using RVM or Bundler? Which Version on Rails are you on?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, using RVM and Bundler. Rails 3.0.3, rspec 2.4.0, rspec-rails 2.4.1. RSpec and rspec-rails are within "group :test, :development" and I've run "rails generate rspec:install". (Accidentally added this as an answer - sorry!)

Comment: similar environment with Michael

Answer (score 5):

This is being tracked on the rspec-rails GitHub [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/258). It's not fixed yet.

EDIT: should be fixed in relatively recent versions of rspec (patch went in 2 years ago)